# Best way to access Firebird DB from a remote desktop.

Tags: python, database, firebird

I have a Firebird DB set up on my computer and I want to be able to retrieve data from a different computer. What is the best way to go about this?

I am running windows and using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install firebird client to the client pc
- To connect firebird programmaticaly from python you should install a python Firebird driver.

For Python 2.x, you can use [kinterbasdb](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/python-driver/). This is the legacy driver and I think it is not actively developed but only maintained.

To connect windows based server database from kinterbasdb you can use

```
Import kinterbasdb as k
k.init(type_conv = 300) #
con = k.connect(dsn='127.0.0.1:c:\\db\\test.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey', charset='YOUR_CHARSET', dialect=3)
```

Of course you should adjust connection parameters according to your system. Kinterbasdb documentation is [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/3.3.0/index.html)

If you want use an ORM, you can use SqlAlchemy which uses kinterbasdb for [Firebird Support](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/engines.html#supported-databases)

For Python 3k you can use [pyfirebirdsql](https://github.com/nakagami/pyfirebirdsql) which also supports Python 2.5+ and under active development, but not supported by SqlAlchemy yet.

Answer (score 0):

Run Firebird server on the computer with database file and connect to it from remote computer. You will need in Firebird client library installed on remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit more info.

Do you want database access - as in "I want to be able to edit table layout and define new tables, views, procedures and so on" ?
Or do you only need to get data from the database using python ?

The latter could be achieved by installing a Firebird client (in essence its a dll (fbclient.dll)) and then use a connect string from python to connect to your database.